# Prevent my IDE to become floating in Awesome WM

Tags: awesome-wm, phpstorm, pycharm

I encounter a little problem with my IDE (Jetbrains products, PhpStorm or PyCharm) and the awesome window manager.

From time to time when a floating window inside the IDE appears (commit dialog / delete file or folder for example), the main window is also set to floating.

I would like to disable this behavior. I wrote a rule to force Windows by title names to not be floating. But this doesn't prevent the window to become floating.

```
{ rule = { name = "*- PhpStorm *",  },
    properties = { floating = false },
},
```

Do you have any hints on how to prevent this ?

Some information about my config:

```
$ lsb_release -r 
Release:    15.04

$ awesome --version
awesome v3.5.6 (For Those About To Rock)
 • Build: Jan 14 2015 20:57:05 for x86_64 by gcc version 4.9.2 (buildd@lgw01-23)
 • Compiled against Lua 5.1.5 (running with Lua 5.1)
 • D-Bus support: ✔
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I've tried to solved it in several ways, but got no effect.
Here is the bug report to the awesome tracker: [Issue 889](https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/issues/889)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this 1/2 working with the script mentioned in the [wiki](https://awesomewm.org/wiki/Problems_with_Java#JetBrains_IDEs).

Add this to your `phpstorm.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# PhpStorm startup script.
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
#


IRONIC_WM_NAME="Sawfish"
NET_WIN=$(xprop -root _NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK | awk -F "# " '{print $2}')

if [[ "$NET_WIN" == 0x* ]]; then
    # xprop cannot reliably set UTF8_STRING, so we replace as string.
    # fortunately, jdk is OK with this, but wm-spec says use UTF8_STRING.
    xprop -id "$NET_WIN" -remove _NET_WM_NAME
    xprop -id "$NET_WIN" -f _NET_WM_NAME 8s -set _NET_WM_NAME "$IRONIC_WM_NAME"
else
    # even if we're not net compatible, do java workaround
    xprop -root -remove _NET_WM_NAME
    xprop -root -f _NET_WM_NAME 8s -set _NET_WM_NAME "$IRONIC_WM_NAME"
fi
```

That fixed most of the issue for me but I still have a problem where the menu's are opening on the wrong display.